# css issue different behaivour in mobile device only

Tags: html, css

http://liveweave.com/BrpuNc

i works fine in all browser but has problem in chromium browser / android default browser
what i am trying to do is 
1:header remains at top
2:there will be no page scroll , only internal scroll , my page is 3 column layout

problem what i get in mobile browser 
Window scroll apppears even when i have set content to fit to device / browser height

html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
    <body unselectable="on">
    <center>
    <header>   
        <a id="logo" href="#"> Header</a>
        <ul class="primary_nav">
            <li class="selected"><a style="color:#fff"><span class="icon about"></span>Rings &amp; Pendants</a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html"><span class="icon folio"></span>Earrings &amp; Cufflinks</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>


    <center style="height:calc(100% - 110px);padding-top:110px;">
    <div id="container">
                <div id="section-navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <tr height="50%">
                            <td>
                                <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <tr height="calc(100% - 40px)"><td></td></tr>
                                    <tr height="20px"><td></td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="50%">
                            <td>
                                <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <tr height="calc(100% - 40px)"><td></td></tr>
                                    <tr height="20px"><td></td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="aside">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                        <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/500945788533342208/BnSNf5X4_400x400.png" width="100%" alt="top" id="101"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
    </center>
      </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css code:

```
/************** main patch starts **************/
a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,big,blockquote,body,caption,cite,code,dd,del,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,fieldset,font,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,html,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,object,ol,p,pre,q,s,samp,small,span,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,ul,var {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link{color:inherit}
a:active{color:inherit}
a:visited{color:inherit}
a:hover{color:inherit}


/************** main patch ends **************/

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;max-width:800px;
    background: #fff;
}

#content
{
    overflow:scroll;height:100%;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

#aside
{   
    overflow:scroll;height:100%;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline;
}


#section-navigation
{
    overflow:scroll;height:100%;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline;
}

#section-navigation ul,#aside ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#section-navigation ul li,#aside ul li
{
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}


/******header and tabs starts*******/
header{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#EE1EC6;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
}
header a#logo{
    margin:5px auto;
    font-size:31px;text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
ul.primary_nav{
    border-radius:3px;
}


ul.primary_nav li{
    background-color:#26292E;
    border-bottom:6px solid #26292E;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}


ul.primary_nav li.selected{
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom:6px solid #EE1EC6;
}

ul.primary_nav li a{
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c5c5c5;
    font-size:13px;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2a2a2a;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul.primary_nav li a span.icon{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
}
ul.primary_nav li a span.about{
    background:url(../images/about.png) no-repeat top center;
}
ul.primary_nav li a span.folio{
    background:url(../images/folio.png) no-repeat top center;
}
/******header and tabs ends*******/
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, and your example may be a bit more complex than what most people would want to invest in solving. If you can provide a more slimmed-down question and example of what isn't working, that could be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, it's the "overflow: scroll;" attribute that is causing this - and is apparent on several of your css selectors.  Not all browsers on all devices or OS's will render a scrollable area with a "hidden" scrollbar; hidden until someone interacts with the element. Try removing this and adding a JS library for a JS scroll bar. I'm not particular to this one but I've had some success with it: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller and here's their demo page: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Comment: @mour - Please indicate the type of scroll you're getting that you don't want to receive. 1.) Scrollbar or 2.) Page scroll ?  Also, which area it is that you're getting the unwanted scroll. 1.) Your content area (#content) or 2.) The sidebars (#section-navigation and #aside)?

Comment: i do not want page scroll
i am getting page scroll in mobile devices

Comment: Your problem may be using "calc(100% - 110px)". You can check here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc - appears to be some issues with Android browsers. I would suggest using another method, maybe set your content heights to be 48% and your header to be 4% or whatever works best for your design. This way you avoid browser support issues.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt excetly get what the problem is, but try overflow:visible; for the mobile screen size.